# C++ concept that checks if parameter present doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have some class hierarchy in my project:

```
template<typename T>
class __declspec(dllexport) EnableSharedFromThis
{
public:
    ...

    uint64* last_valid_counter = nullptr;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) Material : public Object, public EnableSharedFromThis<Material>
{
    ...
}

class __declspec(dllexport) Material3D : public Material
{
    ...
}
```

I have a concept

```
template<typename T>
concept CanEnableShared = requires
{
    { T::last_valid_counter } -> std::same_as<uint64*>;
};
```

But when I do

```
auto a = CanEnableShared<Material3D>;
auto b = CanEnableShared<Material>;
auto c = CanEnableShared<EnableSharedFromThis<Material>>;
```

I get `false` all three times. What am I doing wrong?

---

Update:

Changed my concept to:

```
template<typename T>
concept CanEnableShared = requires
{
    { T::last_valid_counter } -> std::same_as<uint64*&>;
};
```

Now 2 and 3 checks returns true, but first check returns false

Don't think that this may be a problem, but all classes are marked as `__declspec(dllexport)` and `Material` also inherits some `Object` class

---

Update:

Okay, I think that happened because in some other class I wrote

```
Shared(T* ptr) requires CanEnableShared<T>
        : ptr_(ptr)
        , counter_(new uint64(1))
{
    ptr->last_valid_counter = counter_;
}

Shared(T* ptr)
        : ptr_(ptr)
        , counter_(new uint64(1))
{
}
```

What should be simplified to

```
Shared(T* ptr)
        : ptr_(ptr)
        , counter_(new uint64(1))
{
    if constexpr (CanEnableShared<T>)
    {
        ptr->last_valid_counter = counter_;
    }
}
```

`Shared<T>` is my own analog of `std::shared_ptr<T>`

HOWEWER!

I have 2 modules in my project: `Engine` and `Game`. All this code is from Engine module and it works within `Engine`, but when I link it's dll into `Game` it doesn't work. Moreover, `static_assert(CanEnableShared<Material3D>)` within `Game` module  have no effect, concept matches, but when I trace into constructor above, it bypasses my constexpr. Is there some dll-specific behavior for concepts? Or for constexpr? I suspect, it somehow related to how objects being compiled and linked

---

Adding `#include "Engine/Material3D.h"` on top of my header inside `Game` that use `Shared<Material3D>` solve the problem, but that is not what I want. Looks like I have to include header of every class I refer to inside the header where I refer, forward declarations doesn't work in this case

---

Forward declarations seems to be checked correctly only if they present in the same module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `{ expr } -> concept`, the type of `expr` is [determined as if by `decltype((expr))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Compound_Requirements).

`decltype((T::last_valid_counter))` is `uint64 *&`, so that's what you need to pass to `std::same_as`.

Interestingly, Clang appears to have a bug, since it appears to use `decltype(expr)` instead.

Comment: This bug seems to be resolved in the [trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/4PY5anfP8).

Comment: It works, but not completely. I updated my question. Did I updated my concept correctly?

Comment: @Espeon [Can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EjY7Pdo8b). Can you provide a [mcve] of it not working? Also tell us your compiler, its version and flags.

Comment: About compiler - from command line I see C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /ZI /JMC /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /MP /Od /D _DEBUG /D ENGINE_EXPORTS /D _WINDOWS /D _USRDLL /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _WINDLL /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++latest /Fo"x64\Debug\\" /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt Game.cpp

Comment: What about project - it hard a little, since I already have many thousands of lines of code in it. I can try to create new project and re-create this case

Comment: @Espeon Ok, so it's MSVC. [Works for me on MSVC too](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r1TT8zxod). Yes, please create an example from scratch. It should be something like I linked.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oof... It works in this simple example, but not in my project. I can try to send you github repo link. I still can try to fetch important files, but it may take much more time since I have many includes in each of them

Comment: @Espeon *"I can try to send you github repo link"* Nah, try to narrow it down. I have better things to do in my weekend. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okay, I figured out that problem, but there is another problem, related to cross-dll implementation

Comment: Ok. It seems that I come to some finish. I'll mark this answer since it technically resolve the problem, but I recommend everyone to read end of question description